# Typescript Conditional Types and Object Properties

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

Is it possible to declare a generic class(or factory function as in the example) in TypeScript, that accepts a binary conditional type variable, that affects a class property type and related functions?

For example:

```
export function CreateModel<T extends 'CREATE' | 'UPDATE'>(mode: T) {
  type valueType = T extends 'CREATE' ? { name: string } : { name: string; email: string };
  return {
    value: {} as valueType,
    onChange(change: Partial<valueType>) {
      if (mode === 'UPDATE') {
        this.value.email = change.email;
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: You have a working code sample but you are asking if it's possible to do.  Your code can compile, so I assume it's possible to do.  What are you actually asking here?  What is not working?

Comment: It did not compile for me (TS 3.5.1)

Comment: What specifically is breaking?

Comment: It can't infer that email exist on the type of value, even when mode equals UPDATE as shown.

Comment: This is probably related to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28889

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you are extending a string with `T extends 'CREATE' | 'UPDATE'`, I'm not sure you can do that.  This is basically saying "it can be any string or these two specific strings" - and this is essentially the same as saying "any string"

If you are trying to say you only want the input value to be either `'CREATE'` or `'UPDATE'` then you can only allow those two strings by doing
`CreateModel(mode: 'CREATE' | 'UPDATE')`

Another issue is that you are using `this` but you are inside of a function, not a class, so it doesn't work quite the same way and you might have some issues regardless.  generally this is discouraged and you should use a class.

Here's what I came up with, [and it compiles](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20ICreateType%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20IUpdateType%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20string%3B%20email%3A%20string%20%7C%20undefined%20%7D%3B%0D%0Ainterface%20IReturnCreateValue%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20value%3A%20ICreateType%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0Ainterface%20IReturnUpdateValue%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20value%3A%20IUpdateType%2C%0D%0A%20%20onChange%3A%20(change%3A%20Partial%3CIUpdateType%3E)%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20function%20CreateModel(mode%3A%20'CREATE'%20%7C%20'UPDATE')%3A%20IReturnCreateValue%20%7C%20IReturnUpdateValue%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20if%20(mode%20%3D%3D%3D%20'CREATE')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20value%3A%20%7B%20name%3A%20''%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20let%20value%3A%20IUpdateType%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20''%2C%20email%3A%20''%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20value%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20onChange(change%3A%20Partial%3CIUpdateType%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20value.email%20%3D%20change.email%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0ACreateModel('CREATE')%3B%0D%0ACreateModel('UPDATE')%3B%0D%0ACreateModel('foo')%3B%20%2F%2Fcompile%20error%0D%0A).  I know it kinda goes "around" what your original question was in the first place, but I believe that's also because you aren't using a class here

```js
type ICreateType = { name: string };
type IUpdateType = { name: string; email: string | undefined };
interface IReturnCreateValue {
  value: ICreateType,
};
interface IReturnUpdateValue {
  value: IUpdateType,
  onChange: (change: Partial<IUpdateType>) => void;
};

export function CreateModel(mode: 'CREATE' | 'UPDATE'): IReturnCreateValue | IReturnUpdateValue { 
  if (mode === 'CREATE') {
    return { value: { name: '' } };
  }

  let value: IUpdateType = { name: '', email: '' };
  return {
    value: value,
    onChange(change: Partial<IUpdateType>) {
      value.email = change.email;
    }
  };
};

CreateModel('CREATE');
CreateModel('UPDATE');
CreateModel('foo'); //compile error
```

Here's an idea of how this might work as a class (also [on typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20IValueType%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20string%3B%20email%3F%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0D%0Ainterface%20IValue%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20value%3A%20IValueType%2C%0D%0A%20%20onChange%3F%3A%20(change%3A%20Partial%3CIValueType%3E)%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20CreateModel%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20value%3A%20IValueType%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20''%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20onChange%3A%20undefined%20%7C%20((c%3A%20Partial%3CIValueType%3E)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20%3D%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor(private%20readonly%20shouldUpdate%3A%20boolean)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(this.shouldUpdate)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.onChange%20%3D%20(change%3A%20Partial%3CIValueType%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.value.email%20%3D%20change.email%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20CreateModel(false)%3B%0D%0Anew%20CreateModel(true)%3B%0D%0A) )

```js
type IValueType = { name: string; email?: string };
interface IValue {
  value: IValueType,
  onChange?: (change: Partial<IValueType>) => void;
};

class CreateModel {
  value: IValueType = { name: '' };
  onChange: undefined | ((c: Partial<IValueType>) => void) = undefined;

  constructor(private readonly shouldUpdate: boolean) {
    if (this.shouldUpdate) {
      this.onChange = (change: Partial<IValueType>) {
        this.value.email = change.email;
      }
    }
  }
}

const a = new CreateModel(false);
const b = new CreateModel(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment Chris. I suspect that the class example is not relevant, because email is a mutual prop, while in my situation props are not mutual. I'm still thinking about the first example you've wrote. Thanks again !

Comment: In the first example, you declare different interface, that are not depended on the 'mode'. I don't want to declare different interfaces, and I want to "bind" the return type to the 'mode'. Basically I just want a class that behaves a bit different according to some 'mode'. Thanks again

Comment: yeah, i know - i don't know what your use case is so I was just trying to take a best guess as to how it might be used and how I would accomplish it with what I know.  I see what you wanted to do though, but yeah it might just not be possible.

Comment: Your understanding of `T extends 'CREATE' | 'UPDATE'` is incorrect.  This is valid syntax.  It means `T` can be `'CREATE'`, `'UPDATE'`, or the union `'CREATE' | 'UPDATE'`.